# deserialization failure with swift4.2 (xcode10) Abort trap: 6

Tags: ios, deserialization, fatal-error, xcode10, swift4.2

I tried to transfer swift 4 to swift 4.2 with XCode 10.0 release 
then got this msg:

```
*** DESERIALIZATION FAILURE (please include this section in any bug report) ***
could not find 'init(frame:)' in parent class
0  swift                    0x00000001050f864a PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x00000001050f7dfe SignalHandler(int) + 302
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff77964b3d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ffeee8fb4e0 _sigtramp + 1996057024
4  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fff778231c9 abort + 127
5  swift                    0x000000010255e0fb swift::ModuleFile::fatal(llvm::Error) + 1915
6  swift                    0x0000000102595753 getSILDeclRef(swift::ModuleFile*, llvm::ArrayRef<unsigned long long>, unsigned int&) + 307
7  swift                    0x0000000102597a94 swift::SILDeserializer::readVTable(llvm::PointerEmbeddedInt<unsigned int, 31>) + 740
8  swift                    0x000000010263e84b swift::SerializedSILLoader::getAllForModule(swift::Identifier, swift::FileUnit*) + 331
9  swift                    0x00000001013889be performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 34558
10 swift                    0x000000010137cdc5 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7717
11 swift                    0x0000000101322a35 main + 1349
12 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff7777b085 start + 1
```

and this in the end:

```
1.  While deserializing SIL vtable for 'MenuNavTitleView' in module 'projectName'
error: Abort trap: 6
```

I looked for some reasons such as .zero, then even I replaced all .zero in my code, it still have this problem.

Does someone know how to fix this fatal error?

Comment: From Xcode 10 Beta 3 the issue of edge insets is resolved : The `zero` property on `UIEdgeInsets` can now successfully be used. (40735990) -> So this is another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem in Xcode 10.2.1.

After days trying to solve it, I discovered that in my case this error was caused by a Swift class that inherits an Objective-C Third Party class (more specifically the `FSCalendarCell` class from https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar).

I rewrote the Swift class for Objective-C and it compiled and ran without any issues.